# Remove text from Cell if specific words show in another coumn

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substitution

I'm hoping this will be a simple one but it's stumped me this morning.

I have a spreadsheet which in column A has verbatim from customers. In each cell of column A there could be more than one word.

What I want is to filter Column A and its rows so that it removes any words found in column B and then outputs the left over words in Column C.

I thought about using the formula =SUBSTITUTE(A2,"This","") however I can't seem to get it to search a column for words and don't really want to have to write each word individually within the formula.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is very close to solving your situation if I understand your request properly. Attempt a solution by using this formula in a blank column:

```
    =SUBSTITUTE(Trim(A1),Trim(B1),"",1)
```

and then fill down as far as column B goes. Then simply copy, paste special as values into column A.

I am not sure what you mean by "left over" words. If you mean the words "left over" after applying the formula to column A, then simply put =A1 into C1, then copy down.

Again, I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. If not, others will surely post an excellent answer.